# QGIS 2.14 does not work after installation

Tags: qgis

After installing for the first time qgis 2.14 on my laptop, starting qgis with the shortcuts is not working, no error messages. (Windows 7, ArcGIS Desktop already installed, 64 bit System). I have no idea, what could be wrong.
(QGIS had not been installed before on my Laptop, QGIS Standalone Installer 2.14 (64-bit))
Corinna

Comment: Any error message or just nothing happens? I am sure other will ask for more info like the install method and if you have had previous versions etc.

Comment: After you have run the shortcut does anything show up in the windows task manager. Can you try running the programme not from the shortcut? Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing maybe with a different installer?

Comment: Try running the QGIS batch file instead and see if QGIS loads. Should be in something like `C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\bin\qgis.bat`.

Comment: I  started the qgis.bat from the command line. Than I could read, that there is a Problem with the user rights. A Group policy of my IT Environment is blocking the qgis.bat.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the Problem by starting QGIS with administrator rights (rightclick on the QGIS icon "start with admininstrator rights"). This maybe only a solution in my case, because of my IT Environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: trying to launch QGIS (tried multiple versions, e.g. 2.14 and 2.18) did not cause *any* response.

Then I executed `qgis.bat` (in the `bin` folder) from the command line. It complained about an R version that could not be used. In fact, I found an environment variable `RHOME` on my user environment that pointed to an R installation on my system that was no longer existent. After deleting that environment variable, everything worked like a charm.

Comment: Hi Maik, thanks for your answer. I also started the qgis.bat from the command line. Than I could read, that there is a Problem with the user rights. A Group policy of my IT Environment is blocking the qgis.bat.